# Redirect loop with Rails & Omniauth on before_filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

I am currently developing a facebook app which will require the user to be signed in prior to being able to access the app.

I have a `before_filter` on the `application_controller` to check if the user is logged in and if not redirect them to the proper sign in path.

This is the code thus far:

```
Application Controller

before_filter :check_sign_in

def check_sign_in
  unless user_signed_in?
  redirect_to signin_path
end

private 
def current_user
  begin
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  rescue Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
    nil
  end
end

def user_signed_in?
  return true if current_user
end
```

I have my `routes.rb` I have the following for `signin_path`

```
match '/signin' => 'sessions#new', :as => :signin
```

My  `sessions#new` action looks as follows

```
def new
  redirect_to '/auth/facebook'
end
```

The problem at hand though is with this I am getting a redirect loop error on which is reading as follows

> This webpage has a redirect loop
>   The webpage at http://localhost:3000/signin has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

This seems to be more than likely because the sign in process to facebook also has a callback which I suspect is whats causing the loop. Is there a better approach to ensure a user is logged or another method to go about achieving what I had in mind?

I am currently using
Rails 3.1.3,
Ruby 1.9.3,
omniauth-facebook 1.2.0,
omniauth 1.0.2

Comment: Hrm, `before_Filter` -- I'm just now noticing the spelling mistake. Is it as simple as fixing your spelling mistake? Or was this code re-typed rather than copy-and-pasted? (Please don't retype.)

Answer (score 5):

In your SessionsController you need to add `skip_before_filter :check_sign_in, :only => [:new, :create]`.

Adding the before_filter in the ApplicationController without conditions means every single action in every controller that inherits from it will also be redirected, so the actual sessions action will never be called.

You may need to also skip the before_filter in your OmniAuthCallbackController depending on whether it is inheriting from ApplicationController as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Bradley, I gave your suggestion a go and no go on the session controller change.  As far as your other suggestion, is that a controller built into omniauth? If so should I just override it locally or does omniauth support a decorator system

Comment: What are you doing after FB, do you have a Sessions#create, if so try `skip_before_filter :check_sign_in, :only => [:new, :create]`